# jQuery Validtion not working as expected

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I'm trying to get jQuery validation to validate a form. No errors show in the console when inspecting the page in the browser. I've used this plugin before and it just worked as expected. For some reason this isn't validating anything.

```
<!doctype HTML>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />

    <title>Person Form</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Home</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor02" aria-controls="navbarColor02"
                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor02">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="PhpTest.php">Week 1/2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="person.html">Week 3/4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Week 5/6</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Week 7/8</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div id="container">
        <div class="jumbotron" id="personPageJumbotron">
            Person Data
        </div>
        <section id="personTableContainer">
            <form id="personForm" action="ProcessPerson.php" method="POST">
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="txtFirstName">First Name</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="txtFirstName" aria-describedby="firstname" type="text" placeholder="Enter your first name">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="txtLastName">Last Name</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="txtLastName" aria-describedby="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Enter your last name">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="txtAddress">Address</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="txtAddress" aria-describedby="address" type="text" placeholder="Enter your address">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="txtCity">City</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="txtCity" aria-describedby="city" type="text" placeholder="Enter your city">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select class="custom-select">
                            <option selected="">Choose your state</option>
                            <option value="Indiana">Indiana</option>
                            <option value="Kentucky">Kentucky</option>
                            <option value="Ohio">Ohio</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="txtZipCode">ZIP Code</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="txtZipCode" aria-describedby="zipcode" type="text" placeholder="Enter your ZIP Code">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="dteBirthDate">Birthdate</label>
                        <input type="date" id="dteBirthDate" name="dteBirthDate">
                    </div>
                    <hr>

                    <div class="form-check">
                        <label>Gender</label>
                        <br>
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                            <input class="form-check-input" name="radGender" id="radGenderMale" checked="" type="radio"> Male
                        </label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                            <input class="form-check-input" name="radGender" id="radGenderFemale" checked="" type="radio"> Female
                        </label>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <hr>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select class="custom-select">
                            <option selected="">Choose your shirt size</option>
                            <option value="xsmall">x-small</option>
                            <option value="small">small</option>
                            <option value="medium">medium</option>
                            <option value="large">large</option>
                            <option value="xlarge">x-large</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="form-check-label">Options</label>
                        <br>
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                            <span>
                                <input class="form-check-input" value="Lunch" type="checkbox">Lunch
                                <br>
                            </span>
                            <span>
                                <input class="form-check-input" value="Dinner" type="checkbox">Dinner
                                <br>
                            </span>
                            <span>
                                <input class="form-check-input" value="Cart" type="checkbox">Cart
                                <br>
                            </span>

                        </label>

                    </div>
                    <hr>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="txtPhoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="txtPhoneNumber" aria-describedby="phonenumber" type="text" placeholder="Enter your Phone Number">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="txtEmailAddress">Email Address</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="txtEmailAddress" aria-describedby="emailaddress" type="text" placeholder="Enter your Email Address">
                    </div>

                    <hr>
                    <div id="personPageButtonContainer">
                        <span>
                            <button type="submit" id="submitPersonDataButton" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                            <button type="button" id="resetFormButton" class="btn btn-primary">Clear</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                </fieldset>


            </form>
        </section>
    </div>
    <script src="scripts/personPage.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js " integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q "
        crossorigin="anonymous "></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js " integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl "
        crossorigin="anonymous "></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and the contents of the external javascript file.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#personForm').validate({
        rules: {
            txtFirstName: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },

            txtLastName: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },

            txtAddress: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },

            txtCity: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },

            txtZipCode: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },

            txtPhoneNumber: {
                required: true,
                phoneUS: true
            },

            txtEmailAddress: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        }
    });
})
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple and obvious.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dcb99/xfbgkkuc/4/)

Comment: Check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/amwmedia/sw87W/ and rewrite your html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add name attribute in your html form like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="txtFirstName">First Name</label>
<input class="form-control" id="txtFirstName"  name="txtFirstName"aria-describedby="firstname" type="text" placeholder="Enter your first name">
</div>
```

Comment: oh man I can't believe I forgot to add the name attribute! Thanks so much for your time.